# Globally show record count in Ember.js layout

Tags: ember.js

I’m porting a simple Rails application to learn Ember... Currently I have a record count working on my index controller, but I’d like to make it available globally, eg in my application.emblem template, have not been able to figure out how to accomplish this.  Not sure if I should be using an ember view, component, render or if I could set a variable in an application controller. Have tried doing this in all of these various ways and not yet been able to make it work.

This is what I currently have, and I just want to migrate the {{length}} to the application layout (or even repeat a calll to access in each view, etc )

routes/words/words_index_route.js.coffee:

```
App.WordsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(model: ->
    @store.find "word"
)
```

index.emblem:

```
p Word count {{length}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this method of solving my problem, but it still feels like a lot of repeat code, so I imagine there would be a cleaner way of doing this. Would be happy to get feedback.

Application route:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(model: ->
    @store.find 'word'
)
```

Using 'needs' in each controller:

```
App.WordsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(
    needs: 'application'
  )
```

Accessing component in each view:

```
word-count count=controllers.application.length
```

Component:

```
Word count: {{count}}
```